# How to defeat the Bank ambush in Battlefield 3

Tags: battlefield-3

- **Mission Guilllotine**

  - Secure the bank

    - Enter the bank undetected

How do you defeat the scenario where you are ambushed after sneaking into the bank?

The knife is facing into the bad guy, and presumably he must be stabbed with it - but i cannot make it happen.

---

### Bonus Reading

- [From Yahoo Answers:](http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111104143745AA5lj7P)

> **Question:** How to defeat the guard in the bank in Battlefield 3 Operation guillotine - which button to use my knife?
>   **Answer:** For xbox, right button is the knife. Look in your game manual, and watch a walkthrough on youtube for the mission.

- [From Battlefield3Online.com:](http://www.battlefield3online.com/cant-get-past-secure-bank-bit-bathroon-xbox360/3404/)

> After you and your partner climb through the window an enemy barges in and grabs your partner. You're supposed to melee the enemy but I get killed every time. Anyone having similar issues? How do you get past this part on 360?
>
> I'm having the same problem. I keep doing what the prompts tell me, and then I just spaz out pressing every key and nothing works. I keep dying help please.

- Youtube video walkthrough showing the scene in question:

  [Battlefield 3 - Bank Assault (at 19:53)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8VvBg2rQec&feature=player_detailpage#t=1196s)

---

**Update**

When i play, i get the first E prompt in cyan:

[image]

Moments later it is time to use a mouse button. In the (successful) youtube version, the mouse icon is (again) cyan:

[image]

But on my PC the mouse icon is red and quickly scrambles and vanishes:

[image]

(*Battlefield 3 does not support screenshots*)

Comment: @JeffAtwood i do have a Sidewinder joystick and a PS2 controller attached. i also didn't realize that i wasn't allowed to press anything else. Few more attempts and i realized that the mouse input didn't *start* red - but was cyan so briefly that nobody could react in time. i reset my key bindings to default, unplugged the controlled, restarted the game, and i was able to pass it. Put that in the form of an answer and you got yourself an *accepted*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's red that means it detected some other input during the quick time event period. Do you have other controllers attached -- joysticks, gamepads, etc? Anything else that would send an input signal during that interval? FWIW I had no problem with this sequence, though I did mess it up the first time..

Comment: i have the same problem without any other controllers. Does it require the melee attack which i should remap? thank you

Comment: @Maxim99 Keymapping is still lightly bugged. If you bind an action to another key/button, it still does not unassign the former, and uses that one instead. You have to manually unassign the key by clicking into it and then long-pressing ESC. After that, restart the game. This little detail cost me some valuable time.

Comment: @Bora i never could get Battlefield 3 to "unbind" a key - even with holding escape. The only solution was to reset key bindings to default, restart the game, and redo all my preferences.

Answer (score 0):

When you see the cyan prompt, you only need to hit the button (or key) shown ONCE.

If the second prompt goes red, it's detected input from the wrong button (or key).

Often that's **because you're still mashing the first key** (since there's nothing to tell you to hit it once - in fact, it pulses as if it wants you to mash the button repeatedly. Just poor design, as all quicktime events are).